# SUM function in sql returns miscalculated value

Tags: mysql, sum

Good day! I've been running around in circles for finding solution for this problem, i have summed my columns

```
SELECT sum(sp1)
     , sum(sp2)
     , sum(sp3)
     , sum(sp4)
     , sum(fsg)
     , sum(fgg)
     , sum(ffg)
     , sum(fsf)
     , sum(fgf)
     , sum(fff)
     , sum(g1)
     , sum(g2)
     , sum(g3)
     , sum(gb35)
     , sum(gb452mm)
     , sum(gb453mm)
     , sum(gb454mm)
     , (sum(sp1) + sum(sp2) + sum(sp3) + sum(sp4) + sum(fsg) + sum(fgg) + sum(ffg) + sum(fsg) + sum(fgf) 
      + sum(fff) + sum(g1) + sum(g2) + sum(g3) + sum(gb35) + sum(gb452mm) + sum(gb453mm) + sum(gb454mm)) total
     , monthx
     , yearx
     , monthval 
  FROM tbl_incoming 
 WHERE yearx = '" & AnnualSelectYearFrm.ComboBox3.Text & "' 
 GROUP 
    BY monthx
     , yearx
     , monthval 
 ORDER 
    BY monthval
```

where the total(sum of all columns) of the colums are miscalculated, i think some of it are not in the computation, i've been wondering why and what is causing this. Please help.

Comment: There appears to be no error here.

Comment: do you need a `as` in front of `total`?

Comment: Your sum is missing the `fsf` and has `fsg` twice

Comment: To be sure, if all columns is in the calculation, check your query. SO is not a debugging service. Also please share us some example data, the current output and the desired result. It makes easier to help, if you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) demo for us. For more info about [ask] please read the [help].

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(spa1+spa2+spa3+spa4)
```

else try this also:

```
sum(spa1+spa2)
```

instead of this:

```
(sum(sp1) + sum(sp2) + sum(sp3) + sum(sp4) + sum(fsg) + sum(fgg) + sum(ffg) + sum(fsg) + sum(fgf) 
  + sum(fff) + sum(g1) + sum(g2) + sum(g3) + sum(gb35) + sum(gb452mm) + sum(gb453mm) + sum(gb454mm)) total
```